# can I send data from adapter by bundle( when click on view button from custom layout in adapter) to another fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I use tablayout and push item tab by java class to connect it with fragment but I need to sent data from Adapter use another fragment ,to fragment I use bundle and it take data from adapter but when reach to fragment bundle is null.
**I have the following  code in BindViewHolder in Adapter:**

```
   holder.btn_tobuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             FragmentShoping fragmentShoping = new FragmentShoping();
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 String name_meal=holder.Name_Meal.getText().toString();

                 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                 bundle.putString("name",name_meal);
                 Log.i("BUNDLE", bundle.toString());
                 fragmentShoping.setArguments(bundle);
             }
         });
```

then this code in fragment :

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle!=null) {
        String i = bundle.getString("name", "un_name");
        shopingMeals.setName_Meal(i);
        shopingMeals.setPrice(10);
        shopingMeals.setCount(5);
        shopingMeals.setImg_meal(R.drawable.burger_1);
        list.add(shopingMeals);
        
    }
```

**I try to put this code in createdview or oncreate in fragment but the same problem I need to send data from adapter to fragment by bundle or another way.

edit code , fragment transaction I try a lot of way :

```
public FragmentShoping() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    RecyclerView recycler;
    View view;
    ConstraintLayout rootlayout;
    AdapterShoping adapterShoping;
    ArrayList<ShopingMeals> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ShopingMeals shopingMeals ;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shoping, container, false);
        recycler=view.findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_shoping);
        rootlayout = view.findViewById(R.id.shoping_rootlayout);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        getMyitem();
        adapterShoping=new AdapterShoping(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),list);
        recycler.setRotationY(180);
        recycler.setAdapter(adapterShoping);

//        meals.add(new Meals("mamoun","fff",50,R.drawable.ic_meal));
//        meals.add(new Meals("mamoun","fff",50,R.drawable.ic_meal));
//        meals.add(new Meals("mamoun","fff",50,R.drawable.ic_meal));
//        meals.add(new Meals("mamoun","fff",50,R.drawable.ic_meal));
//        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
//        if (bundle != null) {
//            String i = bundle.getString("name", "un_name");
//            Log.i("BUNDLE2", i);
//        }
    }
    Bundle bundle;
    String i;
    public ArrayList<ShopingMeals> getMyitem() {
        bundle =this.getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null) {
            i = bundle.getString("name", "un_name");
        }
        shopingMeals = new ShopingMeals();
            shopingMeals.setName_Meal(i);
            shopingMeals.setPrice(10);
            shopingMeals.setCount(5);
            shopingMeals.setImg_meal(R.drawable.burger_1);
            list.add(shopingMeals);
//       String a = Objects.requireNonNull(this.getActivity()).getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("name", "def");
//       SharedPreferences sh = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//       String s =sh.getString("name","def");
//            shopingMeals.setName_Meal(a);

            return list;

    }
```

thanks,**

Comment: how are you doing the fragment transaction, can you share that code

Comment: I edit it in the top , you can see it and help me to solve this problem, please.

Answer (score 0):

Greate answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Try to retrieve values instead of bundle

So:

```
if(getArguments() != null)
  shippingMeals.setName_Meal(getArguments().getString("name"));
```

Comment: I try it but also the same problem the bundle is null

Comment: Are you sure you show the same fragment instace that you put arguments to?

Comment: I don't understand you, can you explanation of the solution or get a new way to transfer data from Adapter to fragment